# Filtro no Login PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, login

Tenho 2 tabelas: A tabela Usuário, que contém o nome(login), senha e idUsuário, e a tabela empresaUsuario que possui um campo perfil e o idUsuario como chave estrangeira. A questão é: Quando o usuário for fazer login, se o seu perfil for 'D' ou 'S', ele será encaminhado para uma pagina de administrador. Como faço para separar quem possui esse perfil de quem não possui? Meu código atual é este:

````
        
        $_SESSION['logado'] = $_SESSION['logado'] ?? False;

        if(!empty ($_POST['botao3'])){
         $userlogin = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['usuarioLogin']); //Pega o usuario
         $usersenha = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['usuarioSenha']); //Pega Senha
         $senhadecript = md5($usersenha); //Descriptografa
            try{
            $idfromUser = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT idUsuario FROM `wp_tblusuario1` WHERE usuario = '$userlogin'"); //Funcionando, retorna o id
            $Result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_tblusuario1` WHERE usuario = '$userlogin' AND senha = '$senhadecript'"); //Funcionando, faz login          
            
            $Perfil = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT perfil, idUsuario FROM `wp_tblempresausuario` WHERE idUsuario = $idfromUser"); //Erro: não consegue converter esse objeto
            
         
          
            
          
             if($Result != null && $Perfil == 'D' || $Perfil == 'S'){
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $userlogin;
                    $_SESSION['Senha'] = $usersenha;
                  //  $_SESSION['Perfil'] = $Perfil;
                    $_SESSION['session_id'] = session_id();
                    $_SESSION['logado'] = True;
                   // header('Location: http://formspuc.local/login');
                    echo $_SESSION['Usuario'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo $_SESSION['session_id'];
                    echo "<br>";
                    //echo  $_SESSION['Perfil'];
                }

             else{

                $_SESSION['logado'] = False;
                // header('Location: http://formspuc.local/login.php');
               echo "Erro!";

            }
        }catch (Exception $e){ 
          
           echo "Excecao: ";
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
         
        }
     }catch (Exception $e)  
     {  
       echo "Excecao: ";
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } ```
````

Comment: Antes da linha ```$Perfil = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT perfil, idUsuario FROM `wp_tblempresausuario` WHERE idUsuario = $idfromUser");``` adicione `var_dump($idFromUser);exit;` rode o script e poste o resultado.

Comment: @Lucas olá! Retorna isso: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4984 (1) { ["idUsuario"]=> string(1) "2" } }`

Comment: Perguntas com código tem que ter um [mcve] do problema, não o código todo, de forma a visitantes com situação similar, mesmo leigos, identificarem o problema, e as respostas servirem para outras pessoas em outros contextos. Códigos específicos demais ou já aplicados só servem para o autor da pergunta, aí não cumprem a função do site. Mais detalhes em [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) do site. O [FAQ da Comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/70) é um bom complemento.

Comment: Seria bom o autor da pergunta ler com muita atenção esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8677/137387 já que a função usada para fazer o tratamento das entras do usuário é ineficaz para esse tipo de ataque.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Na linha

```php
$Perfil = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT perfil, idUsuario FROM `wp_tblempresausuario` WHERE idUsuario = $idfromUser");
```

troque por

```php
$Perfil = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT perfil, idUsuario FROM `wp_tblempresausuario` WHERE idUsuario = {$idfromUser[0]->idUsuario}");
```

Não entendo de Wordpress, mas baseado no seu problema, talvez tenha que fazer mais uma alteração (faça primeiro a de cima, e se der erro tente essa outra também):

Troque

```php
if($Result != null && $Perfil == 'D' || $Perfil == 'S'){
```

por

```php
if($Result != null && $Perfil[0]->perfil == 'D' || $Perfil[0]->perfil == 'S'){
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado

Comment: Eu não votei na sua resposta, porque disse não entender Wordpress, mas votei negativo na pergunta. Estou dando satisfação por conta do seu [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/553481/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-retornando-somente-undefined#comment985778_553486) Tem um erro muito grave na pergunta que o passou desapercebido a função WordPress [`sanitize_text_field(`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/) **NUNCA, JAMAIS e em HIPÓTESE ALGUM** deve ser utilizada para tratar dados a serem incorporados a consulta inline a banco de dados.

Comment: Tanto o código da pergunta como o código de sua solução são vulneráveis a ataques de [SQL Injection](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8677/137387). Talvez se editar a resposta e corrigir esse equivoco os negativos serão revertidos.

Comment: @AugustoVasques obrigado pelos comentários. Trabalho com Laravel e mesmo assim sempre me preocupo com a questão do SQL Injection e outros meios de segurança da aplicação. Às vezes vejo comentários nas perguntas sobre SQL Injection, e nesses casos sempre cito o comentário na minha resposta, mas não altero o código pois, por mais que seja meio que obrigatório tratar essa questão, para mim cabe ao usuário pesquisar e fazer isso da maneira que achar melhor.

Comment: Na minha opinião, isso mostra a qualidade do material que se encontra ou se ensina sobre manipulação de BD. Sendo que esse tema deveria ser abordado logo início desse aprendizado.

Comment: *Adendo*: É uma particularidade do Wordpress, a própria documentação Wordpress orienta a não usar as funções para escape de SQL. Na documentação da função de escape SQL equivalente a função de escape de HTML que o AP usou [`esc_sql()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_sql/) não recomenda o uso desse tipo de abordagem, orientando o uso de [consultas preparadas](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)